# How To Get The Order Of A Nested List Using SortableJS & jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, sortablejs

I am trying to use [SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable) & [jQuery SortableJS Binding](https://github.com/SortableJS/jquery-sortablejs) to create a nested list, log the new order of the list, and it's children (like a hierarchal structure) via `console.log()`.

I have already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56589385/12232340) which returned null.

This is my code and an example of its functionality:

Javascript (uses a small mix of Laravel):

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nestedSortables = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.nested-sortable-{{$category->id}}'));
    // Loop through each nested sortable element
    for (var i = 0; i < nestedSortables.length; i++) {
        $([nestedSortables[i]]).sortable({
            group: 'nested',
            animation: 150,
            fallbackOnBody: true,
            swapThreshold: 0.65,
            store: {
                set: function (sortable) {
                    var order = sortable.toArray();
                    //var catID = document.getElementById("sortable-cards-{{$category->id}}").getAttribute("data-catid");
                    const nestedQuery = '.nested-sortable-{{$category->id}}';
                    const identifier = 'boardId';
                    const parentId = 'parentId';
                    const boardName = 'boardName';
                    const root = document.getElementById('boardsList-{{$category->id}}');
                    function serialize(sortables) {
                        var serialized = [];
                        var children = [].slice.call(sortables.children);
                        for (var i in children) {
                            var nested = children[i].querySelector(nestedQuery);
                            serialized.push({
                                board_name: children[i].dataset[boardName],
                                board_id: children[i].dataset[identifier],
                                parent_id: children[i].dataset[parentId],
                                children: nested ? serialize(nested) : []
                            });
                        }
                        return serialized;
                    }
                    var child_order = serialize(root);
                    console.log(child_order);
                    console.log(order);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
@endforeach
```

HTML (uses a mix of PHP):

```
<div id="boardsList" class="list-group nested-sortable">
   <div class="list-group nested-sortable">
       <div class="list-group-item" data-cat-id="{{$board->category_id}}" data-board-id="{{$board->id}}" data-parent-id="{{$board->parent_id}}">{{$board->name}}
           <div class="list-group nested-sortable">
               <div class="list-group-item" data-cat-id="{{$board->category_id}}" data-board-id="{{$board->id}}" data-parent-id="{{$board->parent_id}}">{{$board->name}}
                   <div class="list-group nested-sortable">
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="list-group nested-sortable">
           <div class="list-group-item" data-cat-id="{{$board->category_id}}" data-board-id="{{$board->id}}" data-parent-id="{{$board->parent_id}}">{{$board->name}}
               <div class="list-group nested-sortable">
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

console.log() Output Of The Order:
[image: sortableexample]

Instead of returning all of the order results. It only returns "Clone Wars" & "Staff Applications" order results. How would I be able to retrieve all results (parents and children)?

Thank you for your help, if you need more information please let me know.

Comment: is this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56589385/12232340 And this https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#nested

Comment: @Dlk I tried this and it returned null outputs.

Comment: @Dlk I also am using Sortable's built-in nested functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

**Nested Sortables Example**

NOTE: When using nested Sortables with animation, it is recommended that the fallbackOnBody option is set to true.
It is also always recommended that either the invertSwap option is set to true, or the swapThreshold option is lower than the default value of 1 (eg 0.65).

This answer is edited version of this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/56589385/12232340

It was returning null or not working because of id wasn't specified in jsbin

Here is the demo : https://jsbin.com/kabetolanu/edit?js,output

```js
var nestedSortables = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.nested-sortable'));

// Loop through each nested sortable element

for (var i = 0; i < nestedSortables.length; i++) {
 new Sortable(nestedSortables[i], {
  group: 'nested',
  animation: 150,
  fallbackOnBody: true,
  swapThreshold: 0.65
 });
}
const nestedQuery = '.nested-sortable';
const identifier = 'sortableId';
const root = document.getElementById('nestedDemo');
function serialize(sortable) {
  var serialized = [];
  var children = [].slice.call(sortable.children);
  for (var i in children) {
var nested = children[i].querySelector(nestedQuery);
serialized.push({
  id: children[i].dataset[identifier],
  children: nested ? serialize(nested) : []
});
  }
  return serialized;
}

console.log(serialize(root));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div id="sortableId" class="row">
<div id="nestedDemo" class="list-group col nested-sortable">
 <div data-sortable-id="1.1" class="list-group-item nested-1">Item 1.1
  <div class="list-group nested-sortable">
   <div data-sortable-id="2.1" class="list-group-item nested-2">Item 2.1</div>
   <div data-sortable-id="2.2" class="list-group-item nested-2">Item 2.2
    <div class="list-group nested-sortable">
     <div data-sortable-id="3.1" class="list-group-item nested-3">Item 3.1</div>
     <div data-sortable-id="3.2" class="list-group-item nested-3">Item 3.2</div>
     <div data-sortable-id="3.3" class="list-group-item nested-3">Item 3.3</div>
     <div data-sortable-id="3.4" class="list-group-item nested-3">Item 3.4</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div data-sortable-id="2.3" class="list-group-item nested-2">Item 2.3</div>
   <div data-sortable-id="2.4" class="list-group-item nested-2">Item 2.4</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div data-sortable-id="1.2" class="list-group-item nested-1">Item 1.2</div>
 <div data-sortable-id="1.3" class="list-group-item nested-1">Item 1.3</div>
 <div data-sortable-id="1.4" class="list-group-item nested-1">Item 1.4
  <div class="list-group nested-sortable">
   <div data-sortable-id="2.1" class="list-group-item nested-2">Item 2.1</div>
   <div data-sortable-id="2.2" class="list-group-item nested-2">Item 2.2</div>
   <div data-sortable-id="2.3" class="list-group-item nested-2">Item 2.3</div>
   <div data-sortable-id="2.4" class="list-group-item nested-2">Item 2.4</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div data-sortable-id="1.5" class="list-group-item nested-1">Item 1.5</div>
</div>
<div style="padding: 0" class="col-12">
</div>
</div>
  <script src="https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is another simple nested solution https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/blob/master/tests/nested.html

Comment: This kind of works, but it only returns the value of the children and not the parents.